# How to convert Mon Dec 21 00:00:00 EST 2020 into dd/mm/yyyy in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

How we can convert "Mon Dec 21 00:00:00 EST 2020" to dd/mm/yyyy in oracle SQL? The date is stored in the datatype NVARCHAR2.

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: OK, the date is stored as `NVARCHAR2` (which is not ideal - separate from your question in this thread, you may want to investigate why it is not stored as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`). Please clarify what you must get as output - a **string**? Dates, or timestamps with time zone, etc., do not have "formats" such as `dd/mm/yyyy` - such formats only apply to the string representation of a date, or timestamp (with or without time zone), etc. - either for showing them on screen or in a report, or to (horrible practice!) store them as strings in the database. So, please clarify the output.

Comment: I need only dates from this NVARCHAR2 format

Comment: OK, but is that `date` data type? Or some sort of string? And, when you say "date" - do you want to strip the time zone specification, and also the time-of-day (so that the time-of-day will be midnight, 00:00:00)? You do understand that a `date` in Oracle **always** also has a time-of-day, right? (Unlike some other database products.)

Comment: Hi, some values are store in "Thu Mar 18 00:00:00 EDT 2021" and some values are store in "Mon Dec 21 00:00:00 EST 2020" within same column. Column datatype is NVARCHAR2. How to covert both of them together? When I using to_char(
          to_timestamp_tz(
              to_nchar('Mon Dec 21 00:00:00 EST 2020'),
                       'Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy',
                       'nls_date_language = english'),
          'dd/mm/yyyy'). I am getting error ORA-01882: timezone region not found

Comment: The problem is with the input data itself. EST is not ambiguous. But EDT is ambiguous - at least as it is used in Oracle, as an abbreviation for a time zone region. EDT applies to the Eastern US and Canada, but also to Cancun, Mexico and to Jamaica. The latter do not observe daylight saving time in 2021; so the time zone DST abbreviation is not valid without also including the time zone **region**, such as `'America/New_York'` or `'America/Cancun'`. This is one of the many reasons not to store dates (and timestamps with time zone) as strings - you can't see the invalid values immediately.

Comment: If you only need the date portion of the input string, then it can be done - with a hack rather than a proper solution. The hack is to apply `to_date()` to the result of manipulating the string so that it strips out the time zone reference altogether. But this is a different question - should be asked separately.

Comment: Or - better - if you know the **region** the timestamps are supposed to be in, that can be **added** to your inputs, and then a "proper" solution can be applied to the result. For example, if you knew that all should be `'America/New_York'` you can concatenate that to ALL values from that column, then apply my solution but add `TZR` at the end of the format model. Still best discussed in a separate question - you may include a link to this question if you like.

Comment: I am in 'America/New_York' time zone. can you please add the sample with using "dual table" like the previous one. Thankyou.

Comment: OK, I'll edit my answer. It will take a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can accept the input as an `nvarchar2` and give the output as a `varchar2` (you can cast it as `nvarchar2` if you need that for some reason - see how I did that for the input).

In most cases, you would only need the timestamp with time zone for further computations - converting back to a string should be only the last step, when you prepare the results for a human-readable report. If you need the "result" in further computations, just strip away the outer call to `to_char`.

The third line of code shows the **input**. I don't have your data, so I created it from scratch - it is an `nvarchar2` string representing a timestamp with time zone, in the format you showed us. Notice the specification of ***language*** within the call to `to_timestamp_tz`; without it, if your default is something other than English, "Mon" and "Dec" will cause an error to be thrown.

```
select to_char(
          to_timestamp_tz(
              to_nchar('Mon Dec 21 00:00:00 EST 2020'),
                       'Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy',
                       'nls_date_language = english'),
          'dd/mm/yyyy') as result
from   dual
;

RESULT    
----------
21/12/2020
```

**EDIT**

In further comments, the OP asked about different input strings, which have `'EDT'` as the time zone component.

That is a problem. EST is not ambiguous, but EDT is, since different time zone regions use the EDT daylight saving time marker, and they don't all change to daylight saving time at the same time every year. Unlike EST, EDT **must** appear with an actual time zone region *name* in the input; EDT is really not a time zone region, it is only a DST marker for different regions, and it can't be used by itself to identify the correct region.

The OP stated that all inputs are supposed to be in the `'America/New_York'` region. If so, then that can be added (concatenated) to the inputs, and the format model can be changed to add the `TZR` element, as shown below. I only show the part where we convert from string to timestamp with time zone; the rest doesn't need to change.

Note - `ts` in the result of the query is of data type `timestamp with time zone`; it looks as strings (in a specific format) in the output, because the output always shows strings, but in fact the result is the correct data type for further processing, if needed - for example, if one must select only the rows where the timestamp is in 2021, etc. In particular, one can apply `to_char` to the result, with the `dd/mm/yyyy' format model, to match the OP's original request.

```
with
  inputs (ts) as (
    select 'Mon Dec 21 00:00:00 EST 2020' from dual union all
    select 'Thu Mar 18 00:00:00 EDT 2021' from dual
  )
select to_timestamp_tz(ts || ' America/New_York',
                       'Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZD yyyy TZR',
                       'nls_date_language = english') as ts
from   inputs
;

TS                                          
--------------------------------------------
2020-12-21 00:00:00.000 America/New_York EST
2021-03-18 00:00:00.000 America/New_York EDT
```

Comment: @Ankit - the first step is to convert from `nvarchar2` to timestamp with time zone - regardless of how you use that in the second step. If you need to convert to a date (not a string), you can use `cast( ... as date)` instead of `to_char( ... , 'dd/mm/yyyy')`. And if you want to convert to a date with truncated time-of-day (the closest thing to a "pure date" in Oracle), use `trunc( ... )` - this converts to date, it discards the time zone and it truncates the date to midnight (00:00:00) at the same time. In all these examples, `...` is the timestamp with time zone.

Comment: Thanks for the help...can you also help me with above example? where timezone is EDT...I am getting error in this case.

Comment: I have this date "Mon Mar 22 00:00:00 EDT 2021" stored in DB production and I am getting error while converting. Can you please help?